# TikZ object dynamic size, to fit inside tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a TikZ defined note-box on my document:

```
\newenvironment{mynotefortab}[1]
  {\par\medskip\noindent
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (box) {\parbox[t]{.99\textwidth}{%
      \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}
      \centering\tikz[scale=2]\node[scale=1]{\bcinfo};
      \end{minipage}%
      \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
      \textbf{#1}
      \par\smallskip
      \BODY 
      \end{minipage}\hfill}%
    };
    \draw[blue!75!black,line width=1pt] 
      ( $ (box.north east) + (-2pt,1pt) $ ) -- ( $ (box.north east) + (0,1pt) $ ) -- ( $ (box.south east) + (0,-1pt) $ ) -- + (1pt,0);
    \draw[blue!75!black,line width=1pt] 
      ( $ (box.north west) + (2pt,1pt) $ ) -- ( $ (box.north west) + (0,1pt) $ ) -- ( $ (box.south west) + (0,-1pt) $ ) -- + (2pt,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}\par\medskip%
}
```

It works pretty good when I call it outside any other elements.
But I would this to be fitted also into a tabular structures defined at the beginning of the document:

```
\newcommand{\mystarttable}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}\begin{tabular}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.4cm}| m{10cm}|}\hline}
\newcommand{\mystoptable}{\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\myrow}[2]{ #1&#2 \\ \hline }
\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{\item #1}
```

So when I call something like this:

```
    \mystarttable
        \myrow{\textbf{mywhat}}{\mynotefortab{mynote}}
    \mystoptable
```

I would like the note-box to be fitted inside the tabular structure, without throwing any error or warning at compiling time, right now is not drawing the right line and it is throwing error:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 6461) in paragraph at lines 513--513
[] \T1/DejaVuSansCondensed-TLF/b/n/10 CC er-rors could be
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...duplicated. } \par \smallskip \BODY 
                                                  \end {minipage}\hfill \@@par 
l.513 }
```

to be complete, I import in my document the following libraries:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{framed}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{DejaVuSansCondensed}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: Please, organize your document so that you have just one file showing the problem, with the strict minimum of packages/things added --- a MWE. This is also a good way to find the problem, normally.... ;-)

Comment: You're creating `\newenvironment{mynotefortab}...` but then you use it like a macro `\mynotefortab{mynote}`. Environments have tags, so you need to write `\begin{mynotefortab}...\end{mynotefortab}`. In any case, in order to speed up the progress I'd suggest you post one code as Rmano said and maybe specify what you want to achieve.